# "File Access Denied" when using "Remove Properties and Personal Information" from ODT files

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, openoffice, personal-data

Trying to use the `Remove Properties and Personal Information` feature in Windows 7.

To use this feature, you right-click the file in question and select `Properties`. On the `Details` tab, there is a link at the bottom that reads `Remove Properties and Personal Information`. Using the default option `Create a copy with all possible properties removed`.

Immediately, I get this error:

[image: ODT error]

Logged in user is already the owner of the file, and the folder.
Logged in user is already part of the Administrators group on the computer.

A few things to note:

- same error on NTFS and FAT32 volumes
- same error regardless of file/folder permissions  on the Windows "Security" tab
- everything works perfectly for Microsoft Office `DOCX` files, `PNG` files, `TXT` files, and *all other file types* that I have tried

What is up with trying to remove personal information from `ODT` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODT is an OpenOffice/LibreOffice format, so Microsoft does not know how to
handle it.

You will need to do that by using OpenOffice or LibreOffice.
The usual procedure (which may vary with the software) is to go to the menu
*File > Properties*, and on the *General* tab to uncheck *Apply user data* and click the *Reset* button.

For OpenOffice, more info may be found in
[this link](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Removing_personal_data).